# set smaller opengl window width like 64

Tags: opengl, window, size, width

How to set the width of opengl window small under Windows 10, like 64.
It seems the window needs a certain width in order to contain 'maximum', 'colse' buttons.

[image: opengl window]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the principal reason, why you want to make a Window *that* small? There must be a certain reason, why you want the window to be that narrow in the first place. Please tell us the reason, why you want *that* and maybe we can give you advice on how to do that. Because right now it seems, like you want X, but you're asking Y: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: If you need those buttons, then you the window has to be large enough to contain them. I don't think that any size constraints are put, for example, on a borderless window.

Comment: I need render lots of mask images with size 64x64. I Know off-screen rendering can solve the problem. But I am not familiar with it.
I don't need those buttons, they are created by opengl. If  those buttons can be hided, the windows may be closed by key ineraction. But I don't know how to hide those buttons.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you go the off-screen rendering route. Set up your own [Framebuffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) and render into that. Anything else will just be an ugly hack.

Comment: If you insist on not using offscreen rendering, I suggest using `glViewport` to set a viewport of required size on a larger window. Also you could try removing the title bar from the window, maybe then there will be no minimum width.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.
Using `glViewport` may be a feasible way.
B.T.W. Do you have any idea to remove the default title bar from the window?